# How to render a nested resource collection property as text within fields_for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, formbuilder, fields-for

In my form_for @user, I can simply do this:

```
# In form_for...
<%= @user.name %>
```

How do I do this within a fields_for when my nested resource is a collection? How do I get the nested resource object in order to render it?

```
# In fields_for...
<%= nested_resource[?].name %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, there is the FormBuilder#object attribute

```
<%= f.object.my_attribute %>
```